# Is it possible to use OSMdroid with my own tile server?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I new in mapping, and I just set up a tile server using the OSM data. the server is using mapnik to render the tiles.
Is it possible to use OSMdroid with my tile server?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you can define your own ITileSource that points to your server. Take a look at [HowToIncludeInYourProject](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToIncludeInYourProject) and scroll down to "Creating a tile provider chain" for an example.

Sample code:

```
final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("Mapnik", ResourceProxy.string.mapnik, 1, 18, 256, ".png", "http://<your tile server here>/");
mMapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

Comment: Is that an addition layer, or can it be my only provider?

Comment: Either way - you can add multiple prioritized layers of different tiles, or just a single tile layer.

Comment: Thank you, so the example you mentioned is for an only one layer; my tile server?

Comment: Yes - You really only need to create the ITileSource and set it on the MapView. I added a sample for you to try.